# Future - Thread failed to stop

Tags: java, servlets, future

I am using following code(outline):

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
List<Future<statusModel>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<statusModel>>();

for (Map.Entry<String, String> url : urls.entrySet())
    {
        Future<statusModel> future = executor.submit(mycallable);
        futures.add(future);
    }
for (Map.Entry<String, String> url : urls.entrySet())
    {
        try
            {
                status = (statusModel) futures.get(i).get(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                // do stuff with status
            }
        catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Error<checkServers>: Timeout OR "+e.getMessage());
            }   
    }

executor.shutdownNow();
System.out.println("Shutdown: "+executor.isShutdown());
```

My console says: Shutdown: true

myCallable:

```
public statusModel call() throws Exception 
{
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    statusModel status = new statusModel();

    try 
    {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);          
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        status.setStatusCode(conn.getResponseCode());
        status.setUrl(urlStr);

        if(status.getStatusCode()/100 == 2) // Status = OK
        { // Read JSON response  } 
            }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(in != null)
            in.close();
        if(br != null)
            br.close();
    }

    return status;
}
```

Still sometimes when I run this block over and over again, I get this error:

> Aug 20, 2013 9:35:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
>   INFO: Waiting for 1 instance(s) to be deallocated
>   Aug 20, 2013 9:35:45 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
>   SEVERE: The web application [/Server_Status] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation.
>   Aug 20, 2013 9:35:45 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
>   SEVERE: The web application [/Server_Status] appears to have started a thread named [pool-3-thread-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

I have shutdown the 'executor' also checked the same. Still I am getting this error. Am I doing something wrong here?

Update:
I am using Future for the first time. If I need to post more to explain better please let me know.

Update: 
I tried printing all future.isDone(). For some reason the futures that goes beyond the timeout are still returning isDone() = false - not getting cancelled by timout :(

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shutdownNow()` kills all jobs that are still running which is probably the cause of the error message.  You probably want `shutdown()` which will not let any new jobs get submitted but let the ones that have been queued up to still execute.

Furthermore, you need to wait for the futures to complete by calling `future.get()`(which may block if the future isn't finished yet) to get the results.

```
for(Future<statusModel> future : futures){
  statusModel model = future.get();
  //do stuff with statusModel
}
```

EDIT: now that additional code has been posted, I have appended this to my answer:

I've rechecked the javadoc for `future.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`and it does not say that if the timeout occurs then the future gets cancelled.  I've also checked by copy of Brian Goetz's Java Concurrency in Practice (which is a great book by the way; a must read) and on page 147 it recommends this:

```
try{
   future.get(timeout, unit);
}catch(TimeoutException e){
    //task will be cancelled below
}catch(ExecutionException e){
    //exception thrown in task; rethrow
    //... throw new MyWrappedException(e.getCause());
}finally{
    //Harmless if task already completed
    future.cancel(true); //interrupt if still running
}
```

Comment: Hi dkatzel,
I am getting the result with timeout: 
status = (statusModel) futures.get(i).get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

I am using shutdownNow() because I need to kill all tasks that are currently executing even if they are not done as I need to send my results back. 

shutdownNow will kill all threads ryt ?

Comment: According to the [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29]( ExecutorService JavaDoc) shutdownNow() will try to interrupt the thread via Thread.interrupt().  So if the Callable doesn't check for and respond to interrupts may never terminate.

Comment: OK .. I think I am confused about this part.

I am also setting a 500 milliseconds timeout. That should kill all threads ryt ?

Comment: it will try.  without seeing the code for mycallable I can't tell if it would work

Comment: oh thank you so much .. 
that was really dumb of me .. never thought of finally block .. :)